# How to get total count value each day upto 5 days

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"SELECT count(id) AS total FROM participant where dateofbooking='$datepick'";
```

I am using this code. But its showing only one date(selected date from php) count. but I want to select single date and it should show me upto 5 days daily wise count booking.

output should be like this:-

```
2018-05-20------>48
2018-05-21------>58
2018-05-22------>67
2018-05-23------>78
2018-05-24------>43
```

Comment: Where's your `GROUP BY`???  Without it, all you get is 1 row.

Comment: So a user can select a date and then you want to show the next 5 days?  Instead of using `=`, you'll want to use `between` or `>=` and `<=`.  Then look into using `date_add()`.  Finally look into using `group by`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` :

```
SELECT dateofbooking, count(id) AS total 
FROM participant 
WHERE dateofbooking >= $datepick AND 
      dateofbooking <= DATE_ADD($datepick, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY dateofbooking;
```

Comment: if I give echo ' $datepick'; in php. I get only 1 day record. how to echo 5 days count?

Answer (score 0):

You can group it by the date column you are using, and if you want multiple days you can add `dateofbooking >= some_start_date` and `dateofbooking <= some_end_date`

```
"SELECT count(id) AS total FROM participant where dateofbooking='$datepick' group by dateofbooking";
```

the multiple may look something like

```
"SELECT count(id) AS total FROM participant where dateofbooking>='$datepickstart' AND dateofbooking<='$datepickend' group by dateofbooking";
```